# Equating coefficients of Taylor series in the limit?

Tags: limits, taylor-expansion

I have a function $f(x)$ for which I am seeking the derivatives at zero: $f^{(n)}(0)$ for each positive integer $n$.

I can express $f(x)$ as an infinite series
$$
  f(x) =   \frac{ a_1(x) }{1!} x + \frac{ a_2(x) }{2!} x^2 + \frac{ a_3(x) }{3!} x^3 + \dots
$$
where 
$
  \displaystyle
  \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}
  a_n(x)
  =
  c_n
$
is finite for each positive integer $n$.

The Taylor series (Maclaurin series) expansion for $f(x)$ around $x = 0$ is
$$
  f(x) =   f(0) + \frac{ f'\!(x) }{1!} x + \frac{ f''\!(x) }{2!} x^2 + \frac{ f'''\!(x) }{3!} x^3 + \dots
$$

**Can I conclude that
$
  f^{(n)}(0) = c_n
$
for each $n$?**

Or under what circumstances might I "equate the coefficients in the limit"?

(For the particular function $f(x)$ that I am interested in, I have manually confirmed that $f'\!(0) = c_1$, $f''\!(0) = c_2$, and $f'''\!(0) = c_3$. However the approach does not scale easily to calculating $f^{(n)}(0)$.)

Many thanks in advance.

**Edit**. I have a "handwavium" proof that I would appreciate comments on.

*Lemma*. Let $f(x) = u(x)v(x)$ for functions that are $m$-times differentiable on a neighbourhood $S$. Then 
$$
  f^{(m)}(t) 
  = 
  \sum_{k=0}^{m} 
    ( \begin{smallmatrix}
      m \\
      k
    \end{smallmatrix} )
    u^{(k)}(t)
    v^{(m-k)}(t)
$$
on $S$.

*Proof of Lemma*. By induction on $m$, applying the product rule for differentiation.

**Proof of proposition that 
$
  f^{(n)}(0) = c_n
$
for each $n$**.
Applying the lemma to the first series yields
$$
  f^{(n)}(x) =  a_n(x) + x\cdot(\text{stuff that is finite})
$$
so
$$ \begin{align*}
  \lim_{x \to 0} f^{(n)}(x) &=  \lim_{x \to 0} \Bigl( a_n(x) + ( x\cdot(\text{stuff that is finite}) \Bigr)
\\ &=
      \lim_{x \to 0} a_n(x) + 
      \lim_{x \to 0} x\cdot(\text{stuff that is finite}) 
      & \text{if both limits are finite}
\end{align*} $$
and hence
$$
  f^{(n)}(0) = c_n
$$
by continuity (for the left hand side) and assumption about $a_n(x)$ (for the right hand side).

Comment: What are the constraints on $a_n(x)$? If the only constraint is that they have a limit at $0$ then I don't see how $f$ is even necessarily analytic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a counter example.

Let $ a_1(x)=x+1$, and $ a_n(x)=1 $ for all $ n \geqslant 2 $. Your conditions are met. In this case $ f(x)=e^x+x^2−1 $. Then $ f(0)=0 $ . $ f'(0)=1=c_1$  but $ f''(0)= 3 ≠c_2$.

To avoid this you could stipulate each $a_n$ is differentiable in the neighbourhood of $0$ and its derivatives of order $n$ and higher are also zero at $x=0$.